# How to avoid more then one text value from node

Tags: xml, xslt

How to avoid more then one text value from node. I have written logic where my code is working fine i am getting result as per expected output but Is there any different way to do for expected output.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer>
<name>
<Id>1AZlzxIAD 001AZlzxIyyy</Id>
<phone>1</phone>
</name>
<name>
<Id>1AZlzxIAD 001AZlzxIyyy 001AZl</Id>
<phone>8</phone>
</name>
<name>
<Id>0zyIAD</Id>
<phone>3</phone>
</name>
<name>
<Id>IAT</Id>
<phone>5</phone>
</name>
<name>
<Id>zXIAT</Id>
<phone>9</phone>
</name>
```

Code:

```
       <xsl:template match="/">
       <Customer>
            <xsl:for-each select="Customer/name">
                <xsl:if test="not(contains(Id, ' '))">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </Customer>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer>
<name>
  <Id>0zyIAD</Id>
  <phone>3</phone>
</name>
<name>
  <Id>IAT</Id>
  <phone>5</phone>
</name>
<name>
  <Id>zXIAT</Id>
  <phone>9</phone>
</name>
</Customer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your current `<xsl:template match="/">...</xsl:template>` with:

```
<xsl:template match="name[contains(Id, ' ')]"/>
```